# Tabela de Frequência com duas variáveis

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Olá, estou com uma dúvida que não consigo encontrar a resposta. Eu tenho um conjunto de dados de um livro de Estatística que estou estudando [Link para o dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXX9_68q12l8NWo70G70Vch8L_-F4l4-ck5KAPevPbw/edit?usp=sharing).

Quando importado ele aparece como na imagem.

[image: Imagem do dataset].

O que eu gostaria de fazer é transformar e visualizar o conjunto de dados como aparece na imagem seguinte

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Agradeço muito a qualquer um que possa me ajudar.

Comment: o que são esses números que você procura?

Comment: Uma visualização cruzada de frequências... é um modo conciso de vizualizar dados... aparece em todo lovro de estatística e eu queria saber fazer com o pandas

Comment: Desculpe, acho que eu não claro no meu comentário anterior. Você pode descrever detalhadamente como que esses números são preenchidos? De qual coluna eles vem? O que acontece quando o valor "Capital" se repete? é somado os números de cada coluna? é calculado a média?

Comment: ah sim me desculpe...estes números são as frequências ... por exemplo na coluna Grau de Instrução temos dados qualitativos, se fizermos a soma teremos 12 E Fundamental, 18 E Médio e 6 Ensino Superior... e estes dados estão relacionados à região... a tabela do livro que eu postei mostra por exemplo que dos casos de Ensino Fundamental, 4 pertencem à Capital... O que eu não sei é cruzar as informações destas duas colunas... muito obrigado pelo interesse em me ajudar Terry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso você precisará usar o [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) pelas colunas **Região de Procedência** e **Grau de Instrução**, usar o comando [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html?highlight=size#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size) para pegar o tamanho de cada um desses grupos. Após isso, é possível remover os dados sobre **Grau de instrução** do index com o comando [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html?highlight=unstack#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) para eles se  "transformarem" em colunas, desta forma:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Região de Procedência', 'Grau de Instrução']).size().unstack(1)
df2.head()

Grau de Instrução   ensino fundamental  ensino médio    superior
Região de Procedência           
capital             4                   5               2
interior            3                   7               2
outra               5                   6               2
```

Para calcular os valores totais, será necessário fazer a soma primeiramente de cada coluna com [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html?highlight=sum#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum), e salvar esses dados no index "Total", e depois repetir a mesma função mas somando linha a linha com `sum(axis= 1)` para se criar uma nova coluna.

```
df2.loc['Total',:]= df2.sum(axis=0)
df2.loc[:,'Total'] = df2.sum(axis=1)
df2.head()

Grau de Instrução   ensino fundamental  ensino médio    superior    Total
Região de Procedência               
capital             4.0                 5.0             2.0         11.0
interior            3.0                 7.0             2.0         12.0
outra               5.0                 6.0             2.0         13.0
Total               12.0                18.0            6.0         36.0
```